# Identification: Is that a string?

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

I dont know if that a string or an array...

```
char str4[100] = { 0 };
```

That code is a string?

If yes what it printing?

Comment: Yes, it's a string. It's empty, since the first character is null.

Comment: In C, a "string" is a NUL-terminated array of characters. Does that help?

Comment: C does not have a string type. And there is not output function called, so it doesn't print anything.

Answer (score 3):

> I dont know if that a string or an array...

It is definitely an array. It can also be a string since a string is an array of characters terminated by a null character in C.

You can use it as an array:

```
char str4[100] = { 0 };
str4[0] = 'a';
```

You can also use it as a string:

```
if ( strcmp(str4, "ABC") == 0 )
{
   // This string contains "ABC"
}
```

**When an array of characters is not a string**

You can create an array of characters that cannot be used like a string.

```
char str[4] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };
if ( str[0] == 'a' ) // OK
{
   // Do something
}

if ( strcmp(str, "ABC") == 0 ) // Problem. str does not have a null character.
                               // It cannot be used like a string.
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`str4` is an array of `char`'s, so yes: it can be a string. You're initializing it to `{0}`. This means the first element in the array is being initialized to a terminating nul character (the end of a string), the result being: `str4` is a valid, albeit empty, string. Implicitly, the rest of the array will be initialized to 0, too BTW.

Printing this string is the same as printing an empty string:

```
printf("");
```

The code you posted is *exactly* the same as this:

```
char str4[100] = "";
//or this
char str4[100] = {0, 0, '\0'};//'\0' is the same as 0
//or even
char str4[] = {0, 0, ..., 0};//100 0's is just a pain to write...
```

Or, in case of a global variable:

```
char str4[100];
```

simply because objects that have static storage are initialized to their nul-values (integer compatible types are initialized to 0, pointers to `NULL`):

> If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized explicitly, it is initialized implicitly as if every member that has arithmetic type were assigned 0 and every member that has pointer type were assigned a null pointer constant.

Either way, the short answer is: ***`str4` is an empty string.***

Comment: In C, global variables are initialized to zero. Nothing else is.

Comment: @ouah: Nips, I was thinking about static storage. My bad, will edit

Comment: *" `str4` is an array of `char`s, so yes: it's a string"* Being an array doesn't make it a string. It has to have the nul.

Comment: @Turn Disagree with latter part of "global variables are initialized to zero. _Nothing else is_".  `static` variables local to a function without an explicit initialization are initialized just like globals.

Comment: Yeah, I knew someone would ding me on that. I consider them as global vars that are only accessible to the function where they are declared.

Comment: @Turn: well, once allocated their storage duration is the same as a global, and perhaps optimization might even put them in the `bss` section. But that level of detail is far beyond the actual scope of the question anyway

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Agreed. But I meant even in terms of coding style, while occasionally they have good uses, their use is often a sign of something that could have been done in a cleaner manner.

Answer (score 1):

In C a string is just an array of bytes that follows a particular convention, namely that the array of bytes be terminated by a null character. In this case, if you try to print `str4` with something like `printf`, you'll find it looks like an empty string because the first byte is a null character, terminating it immediately.

Answer (score 1):

By definition in C a string is *a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character*.  So here you array also represents a string of length `0`.